# CWM Recovery mode menu does not show up, stucks at red screen

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, karbonn-a5+

I have Karbonn A5+ phone. I did not find any tuts online tailor made for this model A5"+"', though I found very great resource for Karbonn A5, which I presumed that must be same as A5+ but just with lower processing power (855MHz vs 1GHz). They look exactly the same. I tried to install the drivers for A5 as in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90OyT3mzRyM)  and link given in video description, they seem to be installed properly.

I tried to install CWM recovery as shown in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1tP3Um9Tiw) by the same person who prepared above video for A5. It said that the CWM recovery was flashed successfully and the rebooted. But when I tried to reboot the phone in recovery mode it did not show the CWM menu, it just stuck at red screen.

What could be wrong? Does these drivers are incompatible? If yes, how can I test them? Or the CWM provided in the description of the video above may be incompatible with my phone? If yes where can I get proper CWM recovery for this phone? Now I tried reflashing the CWM recovery twice but it did not helped, So how can I get at least my stock recovery back? And how can I install CWM recovery properly?

Well I know I asked too much question stupidly. But just anxious as am noob.

Comment: My guess is that the CWM image is not 100% compatible (there might be more differences between the A5 and the A5+ which cause this). As for getting back your original recovery: as you might not have a backup of it, you might need to find a suiting image elsewhere. If you're lucky, the manufacturer provides such. Checkout [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) for possible ressources.

Comment: @Izzy what could be differences between A5 and A5+, at least they look completely same, anyways which parameters should I look for to come to conclusion that recovery for A5 will not work with A5+

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that. They could have a different chipset, or other hardware differences. I'm not in programming, so I don't know what the recovery addresses. Things like this are better asked at XDA, I'd say.

Comment: Ohkay I got the stock recovery, phew... My phone is detected as `W650` by `adb devices` command. The stock recovery provided in [other video](http://youtu.be/bXw0Z_ITCPU) by same person is for many firmwares including w619 and w650 as it lists while running. So I tried it and it worked. However the CWM recovery seems to be for W619 only. Now am a bit confused about from where these numbers come from, the internal firmware code? But at least I know what is difference here. Currently it seems that am pretty stuck with no CWM recovery for my device. Any thoughts @Izzy. Is there any generic CWM?

Comment: Nope, and there cannot be such a thing AFAIK. I also never heard of any. There might be some working for more than one device, but never anything "generic" -- too many hardware differences for that I guess. But as said, I'm not that deep into development to know all the details involved here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohkay I did not found any custom ROM from this specific device Karbonn A5+ neither tried to cook one myself, but I learnt some facts about it, so just putting them here so that others may get some help.

- Drivers at the said source site are compatible with Karbonn A5+ , though they have been said to be of Karbonn A5 at the source site.
- The custom CWM at the said source site is incompatible with Karbonn A5+
- About stock recovery - I already said it in comments, just repeating it out here:

> My phone is detected as W650 by adb devices command. The stock recovery provided in [other video](http://youtu.be/bXw0Z_ITCPU) by same person is for many firmwares including w619 and w650 as it lists while running. So I tried it and it worked. However the CWM recovery seems to be for W619 only.

Though I still not know from where these numbers w650, w619 came from, the internal firmware code? I will like to know this.

Honestly I think this device cannot take on ICS or JellyBean nicely because of its low RAM. So just stick to stock gingerbread - its fine. In fact I got another device which runs JellyBean on 512MB RAM & 1GHz dual core processor. I always feel that my old phone running gingerbread is smoother than this newer one - at least at basic swipe transitions/animations. JellyBean feels bloaty/resource intensive, but is surely smoother than ICS.

Answer (score 0):

Root your phone first. On GB, there are thousands of root exploits, but I recommend Framaroot as it is PC independent. Once it is rooted, use Flashify app to flash CWM recovery.